# Linking 3 simple squares to data which includes required color

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following - what I'm trying to achieve is 3 squares with each square joined to a different member in the simple data structure `dta`. How do I link the color of each square to the string `colr` in `dta` ?

```
//############# SQUARES ###################
function dsSquares() {

  var dta = {
    categ: ["N", "P", "B"],
    colr: ["yellow", "pink", "blue"]
  }

  var basics = dsSquaresBasics();
  var margin = basics.margin,
    width = basics.width,
    height = basics.height;

  //Create SVG element
  var SQsvg = d3.select("#threeSquares")
    .append("svg:svg")
    //.data(dta)
    .attr({
      "width": width + margin.left + margin.right,
      "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom,
      id: "squaresArea"
    });

  var SQg = SQsvg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  SQg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dta.categ)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
      x: margin.left,
      y: function(d, i) {
        return i * 65
      },
      "width": width,
      "height": 50,
      //fill: 'green'  //<<<<<WORKS OK
      fill: dta.colr  //<<<<<NOT WORKING
    })
    .on("click", up);


  function up(d, i) {
    //update bar chart when user selects a square
    updateBarChart(d, "green");
    console.log(d);
  }

}

dsSquares();
```

The above is part of my first D3 attempted visual, saved here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5plUy?p=preview

Please note: I realize that the function `updateBarChart()` in the above is not yet fully working but that is the next block in the jigsaw so I have no need for help with that ...yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in `dta.colr` is not bound to the rectangles. A better approach would be defining the color together with `categ`, in an array of objects.

If changing your data structure is not an option, you can color the rectangles based on their indices:

```
fill: function(d,i){ return dat.colr[i];}
```

Comment: thanks for help with this - I've already got another question(!) as I'm  confused about transition of an axis.

Comment: this is the next problem I have with the same visual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072133/transition-of-an-axis