# Transition of an axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

To create my y-axis I've cobbled together this code:

```
// Add y axis with ticks and tick markers
var axisPadding = 2;
var leftAxisGroup = svg
  .append('g')
  .style('font', '10px verdana')
  .attr({
    transform: 'translate(' + (margin.left - axisPadding) + ',' + (margin.top) + ')',
    id: "yAxisG"
  });
var axisY = d3.svg
  .axis()
  .orient('left')
  .scale(yScale);
var axisNodes = leftAxisGroup.call(axisY);
var domain = axisNodes
  .selectAll('.domain')
  .attr({
    fill: 'none',
    'stroke-width': 0.7,
    stroke: 'black'
  });
var ticks = axisNodes
  .selectAll('.tick')
  .attr({
    fill: 'none',
    'stroke-width': 0.7,
    stroke: 'black'
  });
```

I believe the above is very much over-complicated so any hints on simplifying would be appreciated (do I really need .domain and .tick?).

My specific question is how to apply a transition to this axis - why does the following small addition not achieve this?

```
// Add y axis with ticks and tick markers
var axisPadding = 2;
var leftAxisGroup = svgBar
  .append('g')
  .style('font', '10px verdana')
  .attr({
    transform: 'translate(' + (margin.left - axisPadding) + ',' + (margin.top) + ')'
  });
var axisY = d3.svg.transition().duration(750)   //<<<<<<<<<< HERE I ADDED .transition().duration(750) 
  .axis()
  .orient('left')
  .scale(yScale);
var axisNodes = leftAxisGroup.call(axisY);
var domain = axisNodes
  .selectAll('.domain')
  .attr({
    fill: 'none',
    'stroke-width': 0.7,
    stroke: 'black'
  });
var ticks = axisNodes
  .selectAll('.tick')
  .attr({
    fill: 'none',
    'stroke-width': 0.7,
    stroke: 'black'
  });
```

The above starts at row 549 in here: https://plnkr.co/edit/fc9hq7?p=preview

---

update

So far using @Ashitaka's advice I added the following to my css:

```
.domain {
    fill: 'none';
    stroke-width: 0.7;
    stroke: 'black';
}

.tick {
    fill: 'none';
    stroke-width: 0.7;
    stroke: 'black';
}
```

Then I simplified the initial creation of the axis to the following:

```
// Add y axis with ticks and tick markers
var axisPadding = 2;
var leftAxisGroup = svg
    .append('g')
    // .style('font', '10px verdana')
    .attr({
        transform: 'translate(' + (margin.left - axisPadding) + ',' + (margin.top) + ')',
        id: "yAxisG"
    });
var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient('left')
    .scale(yScale);
leftAxisGroup.call(axisY);
```

Then I simplified the updating of the axis to the following:

```
  var plotJ = d3.select("#yAxisG")
  var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
      .orient('left')
      .scale(yScale);
 plotJ.transition().duration(1000).call(axisY);
```

All updating ok but the css does not seem to have any affect?

Here is the updated version: https://plnkr.co/edit/tXt3vk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really are two questions in one, but here are the answers:

1. You are right that there is no need for all that JavaScript code to target `.domain` and `.tick` as that can be achieved with CSS:

   ```
   .domain, .tick {
     stroke: black;
     shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }

   .domain {
     fill: none;
   }
   ```
2. To create an axis, you do the following:

   ```
   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .orient("left")
     .scale(yScale);

   var domYAxis = mainGroup.append("g")
     .call(yAxis);
   ```

   To animate an axis, you just need to add a `transition` before the `call`:

   ```
   var domYAxis = mainGroup.append("g");
   domYAxis.transition()
     .duration(750)
     .call(yAxis);
   ```

Comment: ....wish I could up by 2 as this looks like 3 or 4 answers for the price of one question - let me explore and then mark correct. Not sure if it the same for everyone who starts playing with d3 but I've just managed to add in some transitions successfully .. so satisfying

Comment: I've added to the projects css the code you mentioned but how do I instruct mainGroup to use that css? (as you can probably tell most of this technology is new to me)

Comment: `this.750` causes an exception for me

Comment: I just tweaked the CSS to get better results.